# Can I add multiple summary rows in TSQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Goal: I am trying to add a summary row per school and I have this set up in Fiddle.

Needs:

1. List item  I would like the enrollment totals for each year for Smith Elementary, Jones Elementary, etc.
2. List item  I would also like to have summary rows for all levels (ES,MS,HS).
3. List item  I would also like to have a grand total row for all levels.

**[Fiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f3e397/7/0)**

Is this possible in TSQL? I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT 
     schoolid, 
     sitename, 
     level,
     area, 
     grade, 
     20122013ActualEnrollment ,
     20132014ActualEnrollment,
     20152016ActualEnrollment


  FROM  supportContacts          

ORDER BY
  CASE   
      WHEN Level= 'ES' THEN '1'
      WHEN Level= 'MS' THEN '2'
      WHEN Level= 'HS' THEN '3'
    ELSE '4'
  END

, SiteName

  , CASE 
      WHEN Grade = 'K' THEN '1'
      WHEN Grade = '1' THEN '2'
      WHEN Grade = '2' THEN '3'
      WHEN Grade = '3' THEN '4'
      WHEN Grade = '4' THEN '5'
      WHEN Grade = '5' THEN '6'
    ELSE '7'
   END
```

Output:

[image]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Check out [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21740326/rollup-function-replace-null-with-total-w-column-data-type-int-not-varchar)

Comment: Thanks for the link @programmer43229.  I still don't know how to keep all of my other columns when using the GROUP BY.

Comment: can you update the question with sample output it will be very helpful

Comment: @Pradeep, Output from Fiddle is attached.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please realize this is pretty much a shot in the dark. I don't have the structure or sample data when writing this.

```
SELECT 
      SY12.[SchoolID]
   , MAX(SY12.[SiteName])
   , MAX(SY12.[Level])
   , MAX(S.[AreaName])
   ,  SY12.[Grade]
   ,  SY12.[TotalEnrollment] AS '2012-2013 Actual Enrollment'
   ,  SY13.[TotalEnrollment] AS '2013-2014 Actual Enrollment'
   ,      P.[2016]           AS '2015-2016 Projected Enrollment'
FROM            
   [2012Cycle1_Data] AS SY12
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   [2013Cycle1_Data] AS SY13 ON SY12.SchoolID = SY13.[SchoolID]
   AND SY12.Grade = SY13.Grade
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   [Projections] AS P ON SY12.SchoolID = P.[SchoolID]
   AND SY12.Grade = P.Grade
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   v_Sites AS S ON SY12.SchoolID = S.SchoolID
GROUP BY SY12.[SchoolID], SY12.[Grade]
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN SY12.Level= 'ES' THEN '1'
    WHEN SY12.Level= 'MS' THEN '2'
    WHEN SY12.Level= 'HS' THEN '3'
  ELSE '4'
END
, SiteName
, CASE 
  WHEN SY12.Grade = 'K' THEN '1'
  WHEN SY12.Grade = '1' THEN '2'
  WHEN SY12.Grade = '2' THEN '3'
  WHEN SY12.Grade = '3' THEN '4'
  WHEN SY12.Grade = '4' THEN '5'
  WHEN SY12.Grade = '5' THEN '6'
ELSE '7'
END
```

Looks like I have typos in the query. :(

```
SELECT 
    schoolid, 
    MAX(sitename), 
    MAX(level),
    MAX(area), 
    grade, 
    SUM(20122013ActualEnrollment),
    SUM(20132014ActualEnrollment),
    SUM(20152016ActualEnrollment)
FROM  supportContacts          
GROUP BY schoolid, grade WITH ROLLUP
```

That worked in your fiddle. I know it is not ordered by but maybe you can run with it?

Comment: Thanks for trying, that does not run.  I did add a Fiddle link in my original post in case that is helpful.  Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, after @programmer43229's answer, I edited my original post.